# How to detect the rectangle area on a comic book page?

Tags: android, iphone, opencv, ipad, graphics

A comic book page is composed of several rectangle area, and some of them may overlap with each other like below. Also those rectangles may not be horizontal aligned.

What is the best strategy to detect the coordinates and dimension of the individual rectangle area ?

My platform is iOS and Android. I think there may be no API to solve the problem directly. I just wanna know what is the algorithm to deal with it ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: That's not an easy task by any means. The delineation of boxes is not constant, speech bubbles and such cross the gutters between panels (to which panel do they "belong"?), and some panels have no background and therefore no defining rectange. You could write a university thesis about solving this one. Good luck.

Comment: What spender said, but to get you started you are essentially talking about the topic of Computer Vision and I do think that with a basic level of understanding you could get the boxes our fairly easily but the speech bubbles are a whole different ball game.

Comment: Hi, I know its very old post, but I got relevant task this week, and my searches dropped me here, have you found any way around to achieve Comics book like behavior ? related link will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't as hard as some of those comments make it out to be....However, that is if you plan on using a pre-packaged vision library, like Matrox, Cognex or Halycon.  There are already built in algorithms that will be able to find the white strips.  If you want free software, there are algorithms available via the OpenCV libraries.

Learning any of these libraries is a task in itself.  People dedicate years to get good at this (and make good money doing it).

These libraries will be able to help you find the sections of white strips and output the coordinates for you.  You will then have to write your own algorithm (with again some help from the vision library) that is going to separate each chunk.  I'd start by taking the coordinates and plotting lines, then finding the intersections.  Overall, definitely doable, but not easy by a long shot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will take a look on the OpenCV libraries.

Comment: About detecting sections of white strips and outputting the coordinates, would you mind show me some examples ?

Comment: Can you share your finding to achieve this comic behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It's too old may be it helped some one, I guess you want to implement guided view for comics like one comixology providing as panel. For this you need CBZ or CBR file along with CPD file. CPD file have the required data to get the frame of given comimcs area.

Take reference from here,

http://comicrack.cyolito.com/forum/16-developers/38777-comic-smart-panels-creator-open-source-project